# Matrix column-wise multiplication operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, operator-algebras

I'm trying to find the proper operator for a column wise multiplication. Consider
$v=[v_1, v_2, ..., v_n]^T$
and 
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} \\a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} \\ a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & a_{3,3}\end{bmatrix},$$

so that such operation would be:

$$ v \diamond A = \begin{bmatrix} a_{1,1} v_1 & a_{1,2} v_1 & a_{1,3} v_1 \\a_{2,1} v_2 & a_{2,2} v_2 & a_{2,3} v_2 \\ a_{3,1} v_3 & a_{3,2} v_3 & a_{3,3} v_3 \end{bmatrix}$$

Each column of $A$ is multiplied by the vector $v$. If there is no such operator, how can I define it?

Comment: Not sure that you will be able to do it entirely in terms of ordinary matrix multiplication using $\bf v$ and $A$, but you could write it as $VA$ where $$V=\pmatrix{v_1&0&0\cr 0&v_2&0\cr 0&0&v_3\cr}.$$

Comment: Sure, that would work. This is for a matlab problem, i just need to know how to write the metioned operator properly.

Comment: I don't know matlab, but maple has the function ${\rm diag}(v)$ which turns the vector $v$ into the square matrix $V$.  Perhaps matlab has something similar.